# A variation on Nagata's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between Noetherian schemes. Does there exist a universally closed morphism $g:Z\rightarrow Y$ and an open immersion $h:X\rightarrow Z$ such that $f=g\circ h$?

This is true for $f$ separated of finite type by Nagata's theorem.

Comment: I think if this factorization exists then $f(X)$ will be a locally closed subset of $Y$, in other words, it will be constructible. But this is definitely not always true, see for example https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/a-weird-dedekind-domain/

Comment: @user45878 why would it be locally closed (or constructible)?

Comment: I think I'm wrong, sorry